# How to configure OpenVino 2020.4 Myriad Compile?

Tags: openvino

I am converting my OpenVino model to a myriad .blob with the following command

`/opt/intel/openvino_2020.4.287/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/intel64/myriad_compile -m my_model.xml -VPU_NUMBER_OF_SHAVES 4 -VPU_NUMBER_OF_CMX_SLICES 4`

Using `openvino_2020.4.287` from the base image `openvino/ubuntu18_dev:2020.4`

The conversion throws the error: `error while loading shared libraries: libinference_engine.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Has anyone else encountered this error when using myriad compile?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the libinference_engine.so file is missing. Please pull the image from docker hub again.